# Get the ID of node using YUI 3.3

Tags: javascript, html, yui

There is one accordian in YUI and I want element id of the element which height is more than 0px.

Here is some part of code

```
<div class="accordian">
 <div id="item1" class="yui3-widget-bd"></div>
 <div id="item2" class="yui3-widget-bd"></div>
</div>
```

and javaScript

```
YUI().use("node", function(Y) {
    Y.all('.yui3-widget-bd').each(function(node) {

        accHeight = node.get("offsetHeight");
        alert("this is height " + accHeight);

        if (accHeight > 0) {
            alert("inside if");
            alert(node.get("ID"));

        }
        else {
            alert("in else condition");
        }

    });

})
```

Instead of getting "Item1 " alert. I am getting "undefined"

[Working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWr7V/)

Comment: don't you think it should be `node.get("id")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is case sensitive. `id` should be **lower case**.

```
node.get("id")
```

Comment: @Wazdesign and be aware of the fact the if your attribute is like `z-index` YUI would like it to be `zIndex` and `background-color` will be `backgroundColor` and so on

Comment: Thanks Quentin and Kumar . it was may bad. missed very basic while writing the YUI code.. :)

Comment: @Wazdesign that's why we turn to SO :-)